# Creating a Thread that does not exit

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I was wondering what the best way to create a Java Thread that does not terminate.
Currently, I basically have a "Runner" that basically looks like:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    pool.submit(new Task());
}
pool.shutdown();
```

and Task looks something like this

```
public class Task {
    ...
    public void run() {
        while(true) { }
    }
}
```

There are two concerns I have with my approach:

1. Should I be creating a task that just returns after doing work and continue spawning threads that do minimal amounts of work?  I'm concerned about the overhead, but am not sure how to measure it.
2. If I have a Thread that just loops infinitely, when I force quit the executable, will those Threads be shutdown and cleaned up?  After some testing, it doesn't appear an InterruptException is being thrown when the code containing the ExecutorService is forcefully shutdown.

EDIT:
To elaborate, the Task looks like

```
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        // Let queue be a synchronized, global queue
        if (queue has an element) {
            // Pop from queue and do a very minimal amount of work on it
            // Involves a small amount of network IO (maybe 10-100 ms)
        } else {
            sleep(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both questions really depend on what's inside the `while(true){}` block. Is it spinning, sleeping, blocking on I/O, or what?

Comment: it is meaningless to create a thread pool but you simply run forever-loop for each thread.  For what you are intended to do, it is probably a better idea to : have one dedicated thread to read from queue.  Whenever it get an element, then process that element by creating a short running `Task` and execute it with the thread pool

Comment: Hey @erickson: Just added the edit.  Basically it'll be sleeping or blocked on network IO (I  expect computation to be minimal)

Comment: Also, you should use a blocking queue, then the thread will be blocked until there's an element to be taken from the queue, and there will be no need for that hacky sleep. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: @DLevant I like this idea, but it's just a queue conceptually, and not an actual queue.  Not sure if I have permissions to modify the code for the queue to be "blocking."

Comment: @AdrianShum I like this idea since the popping is synchronized anyways.

Comment: Then maybe you should consider having a producer for a queue, consuming data from I/O and enqueuing descriptors into the queue. Then you can have N threads blocking on that queue. Alternatively, the queue producer could instead be submitting tasks to an ExecutorService, that way you won't have the overhead of extra unnecessary threads. Plus some other useful features like getting Futures for submissions, and ExecutorService.shutDown().

Comment: Using an actual queue often can be a good way to represent something that is "just a queue conceptually."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @D Levant, Blocking queue is the key to use here. With blocking queue, you don't need to handle the queue-empty or queue-full scenario.

In your Task class,

```
while(true) {
        // Let queue be a synchronized, global queue
        if (queue has an element) {
            // Pop from queue and do a very minimal amount of work on it
            // Involves a small amount of network IO (maybe 10-100 ms)
        } else {
            sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

Its really not a good approach, its inefficient because your while loop is continuously polling, even you have put the thread sleep(), but still its also a overhead of unnecessary context-switches every time the thread wake-ups and sleeps.

In my opinion, your approach of using Executors is looking good for your case. Thread creation is obviously a costly process, and Executors provide us the flexibility of re-using the same thread for different tasks. 
You can just pass your task through `execute(Runnable)` or `submit(Runnable/Callable)` and then rest will be taken care by Executors internally. Executors internally uses blocking queue concept only.

You can even create your own thread pool by using the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) class and passing the required parameter in its constructor, here you can pass your own blocking queue to hold the tasks. Rest thread-management will be taken care by it on basis of the configuration passes in constructor, So If you are really confident about the configuration parameters then you can go for it.

Now the last point, If you don't want to use the Java's in-built Executors framework, then you can design your solution by using BlockingQueue to hold tasks and starting a thread which will take the tasks from this blocking queue to execute, Below is the high-level implementation:

```
class TaskRunner {
   private int noOfThreads;  //The no of threads which you want to run always
   private boolean started;
   private int taskQueueSize; //No. of tasks that can be in queue at a time, when try to add more tasks, then you have to wait.
   private BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue;
   private List<Worker> workerThreads;

   public TaskRunner(int noOfThreads, int taskQueueSize) {
      this.noOfThreads = noOfThreads;
      this.taskQueueSize = taskQueueSize;
   }

  //You can pass any type of task(provided they are implementing Runnable)
   public void submitTask(Runnable task) {
      if(!started) {
         init();
      }
      try {
         taskQueue.put(task);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public void shutdown() {
      for(Worker worker : workerThreads){
         worker.stopped = true;
      }
   }

   private void init() {
      this.taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(taskQueueSize);
      this.workerThreads = new ArrayList<>(noOfThreads);
      for(int i=0; i< noOfThreads; i++) {
         Worker worker = new Worker();
         workerThreads.add(worker);
         worker.start();
      }
   }

   private class Worker extends Thread {
      private volatile boolean stopped;
      public void run() {
         if(!stopped) {
            try {
               taskQueue.take().run();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

class Task1 implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //Your implementation for the task of type 1
   }
}

class Task2 implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //Your implementation for the task of type 2
   }
}

class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TaskRunner runner = new TaskRunner(3,5);
      runner.submitTask(new Task1());
      runner.submitTask(new Task2());
      runner.shutdown();
   }
}
```